# "An uncaught exception was raised:Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'" when creating bootable USB stick

Tags: 12.04, boot, bug-reporting

Still unsolved bug [here](http://qfox.nl/notes/133) and bug -report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/722019), bug in 12.04 and apparently in many other versions. How can I create an bootable USB -stick with Ubuntu?

Comment: ok I tried these methods:

`1.` I installed it in 12.04 `because` if I use 12.10 I would face some proeblems - `did not work`

`2.` I used Ubuntu 12.10.ios to see if I have the same error- `worked no errors`

`3.` changing usb - `did not try`

`4.` Using unitbootin - `trying now` 

`5.` md5sum was -`Correct`

Comment: I tried no `3.` and the same thing. `Not working` tried no. `4` worked but I had some problems when I go through the installation process.

Answer (score 10):

You could try using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), the Ubuntu package is called `unetbootin`.

Comment: Not working for Windows XP

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 4):

> *I have no idea what is the problem with the GUI -wrapper but this should work in Ubuntu, it works in Debian.*

Check up the `sdNUMBER` and then as a root overwrite the stick, be sure that you overwrite the right stick!

```
$ dmesg|grep sd|less
# cat debian.iso > /dev/sdX
# sync
```

More [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid).

**Example: notice like `sdb`, not like `sdb1`**

```
    $ sudo su
    # root@xyz:/home/xyz# cat /home/xyz/Documents/Distros/debian-6.0.5-i386-netinst.iso >/dev/sdb
```

Comment: ...this worked fine, the iso -file comes with the bootloader -- fed up to Ubuntu's bugs so switched to Debian.

Answer (score 3):

For any Linux , Make Boot able USB drive with Unetbootin. Provide .iso image path  and click write. ( Don't need to select even Linux and versions).

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my case:

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: If you would use an Ubuntu ISO file in your command,your answer would be on topic. As it was, not so much. Just my 2 cents - corrected.

Comment: Sorry, it was debian originally. I think I copied the wrong filename.