# Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'" when creating bootable USB stick

Tags: 14.04, usb-creator

When I tried to create a bootable USB stick, appear this massege below

Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'"

[image]

How can I create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Which software did you try?

Comment: I use Startup Disk Creator

Comment: Try to Use `unetbootin`

Comment: Yeah try Unetbootin.

Comment: *Startup Disk Creator* is actually the [recommended way to install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["An uncaught exception was raised:Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'" when creating bootable USB stick](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173615/an-uncaught-exception-was-raisedinvalid-version-string-gnu-linux-when-creat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few good ideas listed here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media

They include unetbootin, dd and Rufus (Windows).